# Add a small space between tables

Tags: css, asp.net, html, html-table, repeater

What I want to do is add a small space between my tables.  When I use `<p>` or `<br>` the space is too big.  Does anyone know how to make a really small space between tables?

Here's what it actually looks like versus what I want it to look like:

[image: Example]

I'm doing this inside an `ASP:Panel` and a Repeater Control.

**Here's my code**:

```html
<asp:Repeater ID="AcctRepeater" runat="server" onitemcommand="AcctRepeater_ItemCommand" OnItemDataBound="AcctRepeater_DataBinding">

  <HeaderTemplate>  
  </HeaderTemplate> 

  <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel3" runat="server" BackColor="#ffffff" Height="125px" Style="margin-left: 1px" Width="800px" BorderColor="Black" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px">            
      <table width="790">
        <tr bgcolor="#007ACC" style="color:White">
          <td width="100">Account Number</td><td width="80">DOS</td><td width="30">Active</td><td width="240">Account Group</td><td width="180">Function</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td> 
            <asp:Label ID="lblAcctNum" runat="server" width="200px" Text='<%#Eval("UserName") %>'></asp:Label>
          </td>
          <td>
            <asp:Label ID="lblDOS" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("UserDOB", "{0:d}") %>'></asp:Label>
          </td>
          <td> 
            <asp:Label ID="lblActive" runat="server" width="30px" Text='<%#Eval("UserTitle") %>'></asp:Label>
          </td>
          <td>
            <asp:Label ID="lblAcctGrp" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("UserCity") %>'></asp:Label>
          </td>
          <td>
            <!--     <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkEdit" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("UserImg") %>' CommandName="edit">Edit</asp:LinkButton>  -->
          </td>
        <tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan = "2">
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='Added/Loaded By: '></asp:Label><asp:Label ID="lblLoadBy" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("UserState") %>'></asp:Label>
          </td>
          <td  colspan ="3">
            <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='Added/Loaded On: '></asp:Label><asp:Label ID="lblLoadedOn" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("UserGender") %>'></asp:Label>
          </td>
        </tr>   
      </table>
    </asp:Panel>
  </ItemTemplate>

  <SeparatorTemplate>  
  </SeparatorTemplate>

  <FooterTemplate>
  </FooterTemplate>

</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: Can't test this, but would `<font size="4">&nbsp</font>` where you tried `<br>` work?

Comment: 4 is kinda big, but even when I backed it down to 1 it was still the same size as the <p> and <br> tags.

Comment: `<p style="line-height:50%" />` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change your Panel to include a bottom margin.  SO change:

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel3" runat="server" BackColor="#ffffff" Height="125px" Style="margin-left: 1px" Width="800px" BorderColor="Black" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px">
```

to

```
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel3" runat="server" BackColor="#ffffff" Height="125px" Style="margin-left: 1px;margin-bottom: 2px" Width="800px" BorderColor="Black" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px">
```

Comment: Frickin' A.  I was **so** close.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Set the [bottom margin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin) of the <strike>table</strike> Panel .

Comment: I want to retain the border around the table, as in the images attached to the question.  Bottom margin won't do this.

Comment: So set it on the panel  that is around the table